# Export Data odoo to another application in xml or other

Tags: python, xml, json, export, odoo

I'm looking examples to export data from Odoo to other application (XML or Json RPC for example).

My idea is when you click on the button save, the fields of Odoo  is sent to another application to update.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to create function to export data as json/xml

Call your function within the def create function coz this will be called when you create new record in a table of openerp/odoo.

you can use [lxml][1] or [minidom][2] for xml generation 


  [1]: http://ruslanspivak.com/2014/05/12/how-to-pretty-print-xml-with-lxml/
  [2]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Comment: Thank,your first link doesn't work, I am newbiz in Python and Odoo, and what I see for the moment to implement this, I need a little tutorial to continue my training. My development to implement the datas mysql to Postgresql in Odoo, no problem, but Odoo Postgresql to Mysql php, I tried to find information but there is nothing on the web like this.  I use this for php in xlml rpc http://gggeek.github.io/phpxmlrpc/